# In what order should I isolate and attenuate an audio signal?

Tags: audio, design, isolation, attenuator

I have a [cheap bluetooth audio module (with no documentation)](http://www.dx.com/p/navo-5v-mp3-player-module-w-bluetooth-fm-tf-usb-silver-283695#.VRF6T2R4pGY) that outputs a signal greater than line-level.  It was probably designed to be connected directly to small speakers, since the ground on the output signal is floating.

I'm trying to connect it (as line-level) to the input of a more powerful amplifier.  I assume that a potentiometer is a reasonable way to adjust the signal level, but should I put it before or after the isolation?

In other words, should I do it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fipbjN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnQU92.png)</sup>

Or some other way entirely?  Assuming that I'm on the right track, what value of potentiometer should I be using?

Comment: Lose the transformer and use a 50k logarithmic pot.

Comment: How does that guard against shorting the floating ground to actual ground?

Answer (score 3):

Drive the transformer from a low impedance.

The source impedance and the transformer's primary inductance form an R-L high pass filter which determines the LF rolloff of the circuit.

So with the attenuator ahead of the transformer it'll be all about the treble ... no bass.